# How do you animate the outgoing transition of a splash screen in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have created an android splash screen using the react-native-splash-screen plugin. However, I have to make a zoom out transition for the splash screen before the main application screen loads. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a variation of the library:

```
import AnimatedSplash from "react-native-animated-splash-screen";

render() {
        return (
      <AnimatedSplash
        translucent={true}
        isLoaded={this.state.isLoaded}
        logoImage={require("./assets/logo.png")}
        backgroundColor={"#262626"}
        logoHeight={150}
        logoWidth={150}
      >
        <App />
      </AnimatedSplash>
    );
  }
```

Just look at the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-splash-screen).